# Jquery ajax call to pass JSON array in MVC (500 internal server error)

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my ajax that is being invoked as a function when an array has data.

```
function sendDataToController() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/Results',
        cache: false,
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: { FormData : exampleFormData },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("sent data to controller")
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error " + data.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

The array looks like this:

```
 var exampleFormData = [];
```

And the JSON looks like this currently with some more data but shortened for display purposes.

```
"[{\"Birthdate\":\"1947-03-21\",\"ROWID\":\"000001\",\"SpecCodes\":\"987654\"}]"
```

This JSON is being pushed into the array multiple times before using ajax to send to the controller.

```
exampleFormData.push(jsonData);
```

The control that this is being passed into looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Results(string exampleFormData)
    {
        var formDataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SampleFormData>>(exampleFormData);

        return View();

    }
```

And here is the class that models that "SampleFormData" list

```
public class SampleFormData
{
    public string Birthdate { get; set; }
    public string ROWID { get; set; }
    public string Score { get; set; }
    public string SpecCodes { get; set; }

}
```

As is, this produces a 500 internal server error. Can anyone provide any input on what is being done incorrectly here?

Edit: The solution for this was to remove the contentType line from ajax completely and was provided by Rion in the responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things to consider with the code you provided that could be causing your issue.

**Ensuring You Can Post Properly**

In order for your Controller to actually acknowledge the jQuery call, you'll need to ensure that the Controller Action is decorated with the [`[HttpPost]`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiu1-36mK_MAhXH74MKHduPCe4QFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.mvc.httppostattribute(v%3Dvs.118).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHTAHofrafsZSuKFXp4mVZiT87JrQ&sig2=7uAYVT-lmKE2I34_vLetxw&bvm=bv.120551593,d.amc) attribute, indicating it should be used for `POST` calls :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExamineeResults(string exampleFormData)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

**Ensuring You Are Targeting The Proper Action**

Your AJAX call currently is targeting `Home/Results`, however the name of your actual Controller Action is `ExamineeResults`. Unless you have some specific routing rules in place, you should use the existing name to make sure you target it correctly :

```
url: '/Home/ExamineeResults',
```

Additionally, if you have this within your View, you can use the [`Url.Action()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8l_CEma_MAhWkkIMKHZ-wCNYQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v%3Dvs.118).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFr6GlQihVXmqiL3JICDbtjzdrqvQ&sig2=PbI739Ashgrt43-9ic8D6A&bvm=bv.120551593,d.amc) method to resolve the proper location :

```
url: '@Url.Action("ExamineeResults","Home")'
```

**Using Proper Parameters**

MVC will only know how to properly map data as you specify it. Currently you are posting your contents as such :

```
data: { FormData : exampleFormData },
```

This means that the name of your parameter in your Controller Action should match that exactly (i.e. `FormData` instead of `exampleFormData`) :

```
public ActionResult ExamineeResults(string FormData)
```

**Putting All Of These Together**

You should be able to resolve this by updating your code as follows :

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            // Use Url.Action() to resolve the proper URL
            url: '@Url.Action("ExamineeResults","Home")',
            cache: false,
            // Use JSON.parse() to serialize your content to send accross
            data: { formData: JSON.parse(exampleFormData) },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("sent data to controller")
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error " + data.responseText);
            }
        });
```

along with the following Controller Action :

```
[HttpPost]
// You can let MVC perform the binding for your by mapping your content
// to an array of your SampleFormData objects
public ActionResult ExamineeResults(SampleFormData[] formData)
{
      // Do your thing here (as formData is already serialized)
      return View();
}
```

You can [see an example of this here](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/b80ea1ad6eafa5ae9347b0d333f84092) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Most of the time, if you are using ajax I use JsonResult as the return type and don't call a view at all, just return Json(myObj).

Comment: That's a fine approach to take. I was just using the same code that OP originally posted (using the more generic `ActionResult`), however a `JsonResult` would work just fine. It all depends on what OP wants to actually do within the action.

Comment: My ajax is in a javascript file so I have to use "Home/Results" but this did not resolve my issue. I'm still getting an internal 500 server error. The stack trace says "Invalid JSON primitive: FormData." If that helps to help figure out my problem.

Comment: @user3654442  are you able to debug and step in to the controller method?  Are you using any specific routing configs?

Comment: That's fine. Although if you want it to point to the proper method, you should ensure that your actual Controller Action is named "Results". If you use the code I provided, you can try removing the `contentType` declaration as well. You can [find a working Gist of the code here](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/b80ea1ad6eafa5ae9347b0d333f84092), which perform the post and maps your types accordingly.

Comment: I tried that @nurdyguy. It doesn't seem to go into the controller at all unless I remove the parameter from the controllers action in which case it ends in an error when it returns the view. I will be turning this into a JsonResult and adding a redirect on success in my ajax.

Comment: @RionWilliams removing the contentType made it work. Thanks. Now to add it to source control before I break it again and can't figure out what it is.

Comment: @user3654442  Ok that means it is a routing problem (as Rion described).  Using the JsonResult wont fix this (though I still recommend it).  Your issue is that the method name does not match the ajax route, as Rion described.

Comment: Quick question @RionWilliams instead of returning a JsonResult. Can I just make Results void and do something with the data passed in and then just redirect the user on success or should something be returned to my ajax call from the controller?

Comment: If you want to perform a redirect, you might be better off simply posting an actual `<form>` via a submission (instead of AJAX). This would make it easier to redirect when your method was completed. However, you could easily just make your post return `void` and then within the `success` callback of your function, handle your redirect via `window.location.href = '{your-redirect-address}';`

Answer (score 0):

One of the issue with this call could be the fact that you're returning a `View` to an `ajax` call.  As far as I know, this is not possible.  If you must post to this `ActionResult` you must do a post.  Also, make sure your routing is correct.  Running this code as is will not reach the desired endpoint as your `ActionResult` is named "ExamineeResults" and your url is "/Home/Results". Hope this helped.

Comment: Mistake on my end. I was trying to make this code useful for other people and edited some things out of it. As far as routing goes, I'm still using the default routing set when creating an mvc app.

    url:"{controller}/{action}/{id}",